# Is main() always on the stack?

Tags: c++, stack

Is there a permanent activation record for main() on the stack? Meaning it never gets popped off the stack until the program terminates.

I figure if main() always sat at the bottom of the stack until program termination, the stack would have a special place for main(). Like how static and global variables have their own space on the stack.

But I digress.

I just was curious if main() is always on the stack. It seems logical that it is and when it is popped off; triggers program execution. But I am still curious maybe its more interesting then that.

Comment: Static and globals are not on the stack. If main() has local non-static variables, they will be on the stack just like in any other function.

Comment: Functions themselves are not on the stack. They create a stack context when they are entered.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a stack. It's an implementation detail. Also, `main` isn't the first thing to be placed onto a stack; your libc implementation might include other initialization functions that eventually call `main`.

Comment: Since `main` can't be called recursively (it can in C), an implementation *could* treat it and its local variables specially -- but there's no particular reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ language doesn't specify such thing as a "stack" (except for `std::stack` container). There need not necessarily be such thing on every language implementation. As such, there are no guarantees about `main` "being on the stack" (whatever it is that you mean by that).

If we take a look at a particular language implementation such as GCC on Linux, you'll find that `main` isn't actually even the first function to be run. The default entry point is a function named `_start`, which performs initialisation before calling `__libc_start_main` which does more initialisation before calling `main`. In this implementation, the allocation of arguments and local variables of, as well as returning from, `main` can be done in the same way as any other function.

Answer (score 1):

`main` is a function, just like any other.  It is called from the runtime library once initialisation is complete, and when `main` returns, the runtime library terminates the program.

On the stack, therefore, are any local variables declared by `main` and the return address to return to when execution of `main` completes (or a `return` statement is encountered).

Comment: Not entirely like any other.  One difference is that `main` cannot be called by the user's code.  Another is that `main` does not have to have a return value (`return 0;` is implied if not specified).

Comment: @Eljay `main` does have a return value of type `int`. The difference is that that value doesn't have to be specified by a `return` statement.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's what Eljay said

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: No, he said that "`main` does not have a return value".

Comment: @KeithThompson Only if you skip over a few words and ignore the parenthetical

Comment: Interesting. I need to investigate this further. As my C++ studies seem to contradict some of the comments. Glad I asked the question, as I got to get some concepts cleared up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I misread "does not have to have" as "does not have".

Comment: @KeithThompson :P

Comment: @NuklearKrisis Let's clear it up now :)

Comment: Activation records go on the stack. I don't think main() has an activation record. all data members, parameters, return values and return addresses go on the stack. dynamic memory is for the HEAP. These addresses do not have a name. And can only be accessed by C++ pointers. A dynamic array has a name, which is the first element of its index. Thus the tight relationship between fixed sized data type arrays and pointers. Functions are put on the STACK. Dynamic Memory allocation is on the HEAP. With no NAME. Only a pointer can reference this address. I love C++

Comment: Global and static variables go into a special place on the STACK. This is true.

Comment: I think in programming this subject is overlooked. I like it a lot, memory management. Paramount for video games. I think the HEAP and Stack is pretty awesome and how C++ can control it.

Comment: But C++ is basically a religion. I have devoted my life to it. The levels of C++ are deeper than history itself. C++ can create any world possible. No other technology can do that.